# IPC::Run failure - Unexpected SCALAR in harness() parameter 3

Tags: perl, ipc

I try to run simple script

```
use IPC::Run qw (run timeout); 
run "date", \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "err: $?";
print "Date is $out \n";
```

but it failure with error :

```
Unexpected SCALAR(0x1e52f80) in harness() parameter 3 at t.pl line 2
Unexpected SCALAR(0x1e52f08) in harness() parameter 4 at t.pl line 2
```

I use perl v5.14 and v5.10, try different servers.
the procedure IPC::Run::harness (used by "run" command) parses all incoming arguments in loop by big "if" statement. but in this statement no rule for sclar values , so \$out breaks the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument to `IPC::Run::run` should be an array referemce, not a scalar. So this works:

```
run ["date"], \$in, \$out, \$err, timeout( 10 ) or die "err: $?";
```

It is a little hard to follow, but in the `IPC::Run::harness` subroutine, when the first argument is an array reference, it sets some variables and flags that lets the rest of the arguments get handled correctly.